# TypeScript - testing a single class in Angular2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm new to Angular2 and have been searching for this for a while.
I come from a C# background and used unit tests there. I have searched for a while but didn't get to my target 
My Setup:
I'm using the AngularCLI

Problem:

**how can I create / run a test that verifies the result without testing my whole project?**
assuming that I have this test

```
describe('AdderTest', () => {
        let adder:Adder = new Adder();
        it('should add correctly', () => {
            expect(adder.add(3,5)).toEqual(8);
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fdescribe instead of describe for development purpose. This forces jasmine to run only this specific test and skips others. Just don't forget to return it back when you are done.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so new, would you please tell me which command to use ? `ng test` runs Karma and opens the browser